# Document Management System for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, open-source, document-management

I have searched through the net for the open source project of Document management system for asp.net, all I got was CMS.

Is their any Document Management System open source for asp.net?
I do understand that Sharepoint can do this task for me, but I am looking for a asp.net solution.

Comment: Does nothing like this exists ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at sensenet http://sensenet.codeplex.com/

I am trying it at the moment as I am also looking for a .net/asp.net solution. It seems very promising. So far it seems like something I might be able to use. The only issue is the GPL license but am seeing what the deal with that will be. I.e. is you wanted to use it in collaboration with other software.